wordpress, after migration localhost to server in <head> style.css file changed name
After the migration from a localhost to the remote server in <head> element I found linked:

A.style.css,qver=3.5.0.pagespeed.cf.PdPXJn1c-R.css

when I changed the file name to 'style.css' in dev tools everything is fine.
Why WP is linking this file A.style.css......and where it comes from?
I tried wp docs, but found nothing

Is your web server using Pagespeed Module?
